# JDBC Batch update, how many times it will execute in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, jdbc

Anyone can clear my doubt?

Refer to doc https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/oraperf.htm, let say if I batch update (batch size=10) using same SQL with bind variables, when come to Oracle db, SQL execution will be 1 time or 10 times?

From what I observed in EM monitoring, SQL execution are 10 times. Is it a normal expected behavior or suppose can be optimize to execute 1 time in Oracle db?

Comment: you have to distinguish between netwok roundtrips and execution on database side. also batch update is different from insert append hint.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked to has a lot of conditions that need to be true for it to work.  Using Oracle's enhanced version, you can only use prepared statements, along with other restrictions.  And if you do a commit after each statement, that ends the batch.

I would believe EM statistics; but feel free to post some code so we can give something more than a wild guess.

Update:

@ibre5041 is right; you have to look at  network roundtrips, and data to/from client, to determine if the statements are being batched up.

There are a couple ways to do that; the dba can monitor v$sysstat for statistics like "messages sent" "bytes received via SQL*Net from client" etc. and test with batch enabled and test again with batch disabled. The other way is to use Wireshark or snoop or other network packet utility to capture network traffic to see if you are getting 14,000 trips back and forth or far less.  You can also turn on monitoring on the SQLNet Listener.

The Update SQL you posted looks good for meeting some of the requirements. The questions remain whether you are using prepared statements, and whether your application is calling a commit, and whether you are closing the statements or connections in the loop.

Comment: Thank you guys. 

Suggestion like use wireshark or v$sysstat is useful for me, giving me another new direction to further check on it.

I get feedback from Metalink support, he said apps sent 13k times. No idea why he can figure it out base on the EM sql monitoring image i sent to him. However, he advised can be proof by turn on oracle session trace event 10053 or 10046.

Comment: You don't want 10053; and  if you look at 10046 would be helpful you look at delta times, and time waiting for client; if it batched updates, there would few waits for clients, 10053 gives information on optimizer steps.  Be sure to mark one of the questions as correct once you've got your proof!

Answer (score 0):

the sql similar like below

```
update tableA set colA =:1, colB =:2, colC =:3, ....
where columnZ =:10
```

Developer doing load testing for new develop apps. let assume their code is correct, so my concern actually is in db. When the batch update come to oracle, will oracle can optimize execute it at one time?

below sample image developer batch update for 13k rows record and send once to db, db executed it 13k times.

[image]

Comment: Updated my answer above for more details.